# Check if cursor has results

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a database to store date and want a single column returned based on which id is given in the where claus.

```
    public String getPmax(String serial) {

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_SERIAL, KEY_PMAX};      
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "serial = " + serial,
    null, null, null, null);

    String result = "nothing found";

    if(c != null) {

        int iPmax = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PMAX); 

        c.moveToFirst();
        result = c.getString(iPmax);

    }

    return result;  

}
```

This code works if I use a serial that is in the database but it gives me a force close when i am using a serial that's not in the database!

it says:

```
04-11 16:31:19.423: E/AndroidRuntime(21226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.janjanus.solardetect/nl.janjanus.solardetect.DatabaseView}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: g: , while compiling: SELECT serial, pmax FROM SolareCel WHERE serial = g
```

So my question is: How do I check if there is result? or do I need to check if the serial given is a serial that is in the database?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
    if (!(mCursor.moveToFirst()) || mCursor.getCount() ==0){
     //cursor is empty
}
```

Comment: The cursor has no rows, it's empty but the above tests still fail, why is that? Is there any other check? This is really baffling.

Comment: Note: this has the side effect of setting the cursor to the first position.  Can cause a problem if passing a cursor object that has been moved to a specific position to another function and then expected to still be at the position :)

Answer (score 4):

If you look closely, the error is that the SQL is faulty.
It reads the `g` as a column. You have to encase it in apostrophes like so `'g'`.

In your case, the line where you get the cursor should be:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "serial = '" + serial + "'",
    null, null, null, null);
```

As to checking whether the cursor has no results, look at Samir Mangroliya's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the Cursor has elements:

```
boolean isEmpty = cursor.getCount() < 1;
```

AFAIK, the Cursor never returns null when there is no row which the requested conditions, just return a empty Cursor.

Comment: Only the Exception worked the check doesn't work for me. Is there no other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = cursor.getCount(); //this will return number of records in current cursor
if ( x == 0 ) {
     // there are no records
} else {
    // do your stuff
}
```